# Context null when opening camera in landscape from portrait activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera, android-lifecycle

I opening the camera from a portrait activity. On activity result I am calling a asynctask and passing context of activity in it. If I opens camera in portrait mode everything works fine but in landscape mode I am getting context null inside my asynctask.

Comment: because when orientation change, your activity is restart...

Comment: Try setting `android:configChanges="orientation"` to the activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding onConfigurationChanged in my FragmentActivity solved my problem.

```
   @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just put below line in your activity in manifest file:

```
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```